# Why does MemoryConstrained have an upper limit on the constraint?

Tags: memory

When evaluating MemoryConstrained for a large memory limit:

```
MemoryConstrained[Print["aaa"],10^10]
```

I get:

```
MemoryConstrained::ipnfm: Positive machine-sized integer or Infinity expected at position 2 in MemoryConstrained[Print[aaa],10^10]. >>
```

I have tested to find the limit, and is exactly 4294967295 bytes. Is there a reason for this? I need a larger memory limit.

I am using Mathematica 9.0.1 and 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with the OS X version of Mathematica 8.0.4 or 9.0.1.  (Both are 64-bit versions.)  What OS are you using and what version of Mathematica?  Also, is it a 32-bit or a 64-bit version?

Comment: 32-bit programs simply can't use more memory than this limit (more typically: half this limit).  I also can't reproduce the problem with a 64-bit Mathematica 9 on Windows.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9.0.1 and 32-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a specific limitation of Mathematica, but a limitation of 32-bit addressing and your 32-bit operating system.  64-bit versions of Mathematica do accept higher limits in `MemoryConstrained`.

What "32-bit" means is precisely that memory is indexed with integers stored on 32-bits, i.e. at most `2^32 = 4294967296` bytes can be addressed.  A program running in 32-bit mode simply cannot use more than this much memory, i.e. 4 GB.  In practice, the limit is more typically 2 GB.

Even if your computer has more than 4 GB of memory, if you use a 32-bit operating system, it can't take advantage of more than 4 GB (and in the case of Windows single programs will typically be able to use no more than 2 GB).

Comment: Ok, I tested the code on the computer I want to run the script and It worked. It is 64 bits. Thank you.

Comment: To run on both systems: MemoryLimit[]:=If[StringMatchQ[$System,"*64-bit*"],8*1024^3,1024^3]. 8 GB on the node and 1 GB on my computer.

Comment: @Giovanni `$SystemWordLength` tells you if this version of Mathematica is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Hmm nice! I will use that instead.

Comment: When I posted the code above it left out the * from *64-bit*. That will not work. Maybe you can just include that code (or the better version with $SystemWordLength) as a sidenote in your answer for others who may need. :)

Comment: Nice answer, but "Even if your computer has more than 4 GB of memory, if you use a 32-bit operating system, it can't take advantage of more than 4 GB" is incorrect. Pre-64Bit OS ubiquity I regularly used programs that did so. +1 for answer though.

Comment: @rasher I am aware that it is possible to address more than 4 GB of memory on some 32-bit processors, but I know very little about it and I never used it in practice.  Since you know more about this, feel free to fix the answer or post another one.  Unfortunately I can't as my knowledge on this topic is limited.  I can community wiki it if you need.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Probably something for *systems.stackexchange* (if such exists), good examples are *Ram disk* (e.g. http://pcgamingtips.blogspot.com/2010/04/yes-virginia-32-bit-windows-can-use.html ), *SQL Server* (better known as *Microsoft SQL Server*), etc. I just know you're a stickler for correctness like me ;-}